# GCC ARM C compiler not respecting -std=c99 for %llx printf formatting code

Tags: c, formatting, printf, long-long

I'm trying to print some 64-bit unsigned integers using something like this:

```
uint64_t x = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
printf("Value: %016llx \n", x);
```

and I get this in response:

```
0000000000000000lx
```

If I change the formatting string to %016lx I get a compile warning for using the wrong type and it only prints the lower 32 bits:

```
00000000FFFFFFFF
```

I've got the -std=c99 string in my compiler options, which should enforce the ll option, right?

For reference, this is the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler (v4.7.3) that ships with the latest version of Silicon Labs' Simplicity Studio IDE.

Comment: What's your C library?

Comment: This isn't a characteristic of the compiler, it's a problem with your C library.  Fix it, or use a different one?

Comment: You did include `stdio.h` right?

Comment: Yep, stdio.h is included (along with ctype.h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int
main(void)
{
    uint64_t n = 0x123456789;

    printf("n = %#" PRIx64 "\n", n);

    return (0);
}
```

Implementation of printf or scanf depends on libc your're using and may not support **long long**. Please, check it by printing value of PRIx64 - I guess in your case it will be "lx" instead of "llx".

Pasting a part of inttype.h of ARM toolchain [gcc-arm-embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)

```
/* 64-bit types */
#if __have_long64
#define __PRI64(x) __STRINGIFY(l##x)
#define __SCN64(x) __STRINGIFY(l##x)
#elif __have_longlong64
#define __PRI64(x) __STRINGIFY(ll##x)
#define __SCN64(x) __STRINGIFY(ll##x)
#else
#define __PRI64(x) __STRINGIFY(x)
#define __SCN64(x) __STRINGIFY(x)
#endif
...
#define PRIx64          __PRI64(x)
#define PRIX64          __PRI64(X)
```

Comment: +1, but could you perhaps add some explanation? That would make it a really great answer :)

Comment: A C library that doesn't support `%llx` is unlikely to have `PRIx64` - presumably it would have to *be* `llx`.

Comment: Yeah the library doesn't know what to do with PRIx64: `error: expected ')' before 'PRIx64'`

Comment: Aah, after adding the `#include <inttypes.h>` it compiles and gives me `n = lx`

Comment: Based on that output I'd assume that I am unable to print long longs using the current C library I have, though I find this line in inttypes.h confusing:  `#define __PRI64(x) __STRINGIFY(ll##x)`

Comment: Please note that long long int and long int are not the same type but they happen to be the same size.